# Is there a way to only add code to a method without overriding it completely in c#?

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

Is there any way to only add code to a method from a subclass without overriding it completely like the "override" + "virtual" does in c#.
I find myself writing some duplicate code in my override methods. And not sure what to do about it

Comment: Refactor common code in a helper method in the base class that's *protected*.

Comment: thanks, I came up with a solution thou. Turns out I wasnt thinking. In the override method i could just write base.MethodName(). then add some code before or after :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use override and virtual with a different mechanism. For example,

```
class MyBase
    {
        private int MyVar;
        public virtual void DoStuff(int i , int j)
        {
            MyVar = i + j; //This is your common code which is added in base class

        }
    }


    class OverridClass : MyBase
    {
        private int MyNewCount;
        public override void DoStuff(int i, int j)
        {
            MyNewCount = i + j;
            base.DoStuff(i, j); //This is how you reuse your common code and write the code which is more specific to this method

        }
    }`
```